# What is the meaning of + in a regex?

Tags: regex, symbols

What does the plus symbol in regex mean?

Comment: Can you please post a sample?

Comment: `/s+a+m+p+l+e+/`

Comment: ^^ matches `sample`, `samplee`, and `sssaaaaaammmppplllllle` but not `smple`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`+` can actually have two meanings, depending on context.

Like the other answers mentioned, `+` usually is a [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) operator, and causes the preceding token to repeat one or more times. `a+` would be expressed as `aa*` in [formal language theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions#Formal_language_theory), and could also be expressed as `a{1,}` (match a minimum of 1 times and a maximum of infinite times).

---

However, `+` can also make other quantifiers [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) if it follows a repetition operator (ie `?+`, `*+`, `++` or `{m,n}+`). A possessive quantifier is an advanced feature of some regex flavours (PCRE, Java and the JGsoft engine) which tells the engine not to backtrack once a match has been made.

To understand how this works, we need to understand two concepts of regex engines: *greediness* and *backtracking*. Greediness means that in general regexes will try to consume as many characters as they can. Let's say our pattern is `.*` (the [dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) is a special construct in regexes which means *any character*<sup>1</sup>; the star means match zero or more times), and your target is `aaaaaaaab`. The entire string will be consumed, because the entire string is the longest match that satisfies the pattern.

However, let's say we change the pattern to `.*b`. Now, when the regex engine tries to match against `aaaaaaaab`, the `.*` will again consume the entire string. However, since the engine will have reached the end of the string and the pattern is not yet satisfied (the `.*` consumed everything but the pattern still has to match `b` afterwards), it will *backtrack*, one character at a time, and try to match `b`. The first backtrack will make the `.*` consume `aaaaaaaa`, and then `b` can consume `b`, and the pattern succeeds.

Possessive quantifiers are also greedy, but as mentioned, once they return a match, the engine can no longer backtrack past that point. So if we change our pattern to `.*+b` (match any character zero or more times, possessively, followed by a `b`), and try to match `aaaaaaaab`, again the `.*` will consume the whole string, but then since it is possessive, backtracking information is discarded, and the b cannot be matched so the pattern fails.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In most engines, the dot will not match a newline character, unless the `/s` ("singleline" or "dotall") [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) is specified.</sup>

Comment: +1; possessive quantifiers only work in Java, PCRE, or the JGSoft regex engine, though. Ruby, Perl, and .NET use atomic groups `(?>.*)`.

Comment: @Tim I alluded to that, but I've now made it more explicit in my answer.

Comment: @Tim: Perl does support possesive quantifiers, probably since 5.10

Comment: @ninjalj: Thanks for the info. It appears that [this comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) is not up to date anymore, then.

Comment: Awesome answer! Really helped me understand the + alot. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

In most implementations `+` means "one or more".

In some theoretical writings `+` is used to mean "or" (most implementations use the `|` symbol for that).

Answer (score 11):

1 or more of previous expression.

`[0-9]+`

Would match:

> 1234567890

In:

> I have 1234567890 dollars

Answer (score 6):

One or more occurences of the preceding symbols.

E.g. `a+` means the letter `a` one or more times. Thus, `a` matches `a`, `aa`, `aaaaaa` but not an empty string.

If you know what the asterisk (`*`) means, then you can express `(exp)+` as `(exp)(exp)*`, where `(exp)` is any regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

A lot depends on where `+` symbol appears and what the regex flavor is.

In [posix-bre](/questions/tagged/posix-bre) and [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) (in a non-very magic mode) flavor, `+` matches a literal `+` char. E.g. `sed 's/+//g' file > newfile` removes all `+` chars in `file`. If you want to use `+` as a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) here, use `\+` (supported in GNU tools), or replace with `\{1,\}` or double the quantified pattern and remove the quantifier from the first part and add `*` (zero or more occurrences quantifier) after the other (e.g. `sed 's/c++*//'` removes `c` followed with one or more `+` chars).

In [posix-ere](/questions/tagged/posix-ere) and other regex flavors, **outside a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)** (`[...]`), `+` acts as a *quantifier* meaning "one or more, but as many as possible, occurrences of the quantified pattern*. E.g. in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), `s.replace(/\++/g, '-')` will replace a string like `++++` with a single `-`. *Note* that in NFA regex flavors `+` has a [lazy counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8575281/3832970), `+?`, that matches "one or more, but as *few* as possible, occurrences of the quantified pattern".

**Inside a character class**, the `+` char is treated as a literal char, **in every regex flavor**. `[+]` always matches a single `+` literal char. E.g. in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), `Regex.Replace("1+2=3", @"[+]", "-")` will result in `1-2=3`. *Note* it is not a good idea to use a single char inside a character class, only use a character class for two or more chars, or for charsets. E.g. `[+0-9]` matches a `+` or any ASCII digit chars. In [php](/questions/tagged/php), `preg_replace('~[\s+]+~', '-', '1  2+++3')` will result in `1-2-3` since the regex matches one or more (due to last `+` that  is a quantifier) whitespaces (`\s`) or plus chars (`+` insdide the character class).

The `+` symbol can also be a part of the [*possessive quantifier*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) in some PCRE-like regex flavors ([php](/questions/tagged/php), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), [java](/questions/tagged/java), [boost](/questions/tagged/boost), [icu](/questions/tagged/icu), etc (but no in [python](/questions/tagged/python) `re`, [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)). E.g. `C\+++(?!\d)` in [php](/questions/tagged/php) PCRE would match `C` and then one or more `+` symbols (`\+` - a literal `+` and `++` one more occurrences with allowing to backtrack into this quantified pattern) not followed with a digit. If there is a digit after plus chars the whole match fails. Other examples: `a?+` (one or zero `a` chars), `a{1,3}+` (one to three `a` chars as many as possible), `a{3}+` (=`a{3}`, three `a`s), `a*+` matches zero or more `a` chars.