# Regex plus vs star difference?

Tags: php, regex

What is the difference between:

```
(.+?)
```

and

```
(.*?)
```

when I use it in my php `preg_match` regex?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

They are called quantifiers.

`*` 0 or more of the preceding expression

`+` 1 or more of the preceding expression

Per default a quantifier is greedy, that means it matches as many characters as possible.

The `?` after a quantifier changes the behaviour to make this quantifier "ungreedy", means it will match as little as possible.

**Example greedy/ungreedy**

For example on the string "*abab*"

`a.*b` will match "abab" (preg_match_all will return one match, the "abab")

while `a.*?b` will match only the starting "ab" (preg_match_all will return two matches, "ab")

You can test your regexes online e.g. on Regexr, [see the greedy example here](http://regexr.com?2vhbb)

Comment: "lazy" is the more common term for "ungreedy"

Comment: The example is incorrect. Both `(.+?)` and `(.*?)` behave differently in a various position of regular expressions which are `a(.+?)`, `(.+?)b`, `a(.+?)b`, `a(.*?)`, `(.*?)b`, `a(.*?)b`.

Comment: Why wouldn't a.*b give back "ab"? Isn't it saying "word that has between a and b, 0 or more characters", therefore, ab has zero character between and could be a match. Why is this incorrect?

Comment: @HelloWorld, this has to do with the greediness I explained above. `.*` will match as much as possible. If you want to stop as early as possible, then you have to make it ungreedy `.*?`

Comment: FYI for newbies: `a.*?b` will match both the 1st and 2nd "ab"s in "abab", if you use "g" (global) flag. Also, the term "ungreedy" is better than "lazy" in this specific explanation because "lazy" is a commonly used term in programming, and it's a bit different from what `?` does in this example.

Answer (score 24):

The first (`+`) is *one or more characters*. The second (`*`) is *zero or more characters*.

Both have greedy (default) and lazy (`?`) variants

```
/d+?
/d*?
```

Answer (score 17):

In RegEx, `{i,f}` means "between `i` to `f` matches". Let's take a look at the following examples:

- `{3,7}` means between 3 to 7 matches
- `{,10}` means up to 10 matches with no lower limit (i.e. the low limit is 0)
- `{3,}` means at least 3 matches with no upper limit (i.e. the high limit is infinity)
- `{,}` means no upper limit or lower limit for the number of matches (i.e. the lower limit is 0 and the upper limit is infinity)
- `{5}` means exactly 4

Most good languages contain abbreviations, so does RegEx:

- `+` is the shorthand for `{1,}`
- `*` is the shorthand for `{,}`
- `?` is the shorthand for `{,1}`

This means `+` requires at least 1 match while `*` accepts any number of matches or no matches at all and `?` accepts no more than 1 match or zero matches.

Credit: Codecademy.com

Answer (score 11):

`+` matches at least one character

`*` matches any number (including 0) of characters

The `?` indicates a lazy expression, so it will match as few characters as possible.

Answer (score 10):

A `+` matches **one or more** instances of the preceding pattern. A `*` matches **zero or more** instances of the preceding pattern.

So basically, if you use a `+` there must be at least one instance of the pattern, if you use `*` it will still match if there are no instances of it.

Answer (score 10):

Consider below is the string to match.

```
ab
```

The pattern `(ab.*)` will return a match for capture group with result of `ab`

While the pattern `(ab.+)` will not match and not returning anything.

But if you change the string to following, it will return `aba` for pattern `(ab.+)`

```
aba
```

Answer (score 6):

`+` is minimal one, `*` can be zero as well.

Comment: `"+ is minimal one"` what does this sentence mean?

Comment: I find these "definitions" to be misleading.

Answer (score 5):

A star is very similar to a plus, the only difference is that while the plus matches 1 or more of the preceding character/group, the star matches 0 or more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the previous answers fail to highlight a simple example:

for example we have an array:

```
numbers = [5, 15]
```

The following regex expression `^[0-9]+` matches: `15` only.
However, `^[0-9]*` matches both `5 and 15`. The difference is that the `+` operator requires at least one ***duplicate*** of the preceding regex expression

Comment: Um, what?!? Why is this answer uv'ed at all?  This is simply incorrect.  Both patterns will definitely match strings `5` and `15`.