# jersey @PathParam: how to pass a variable which contains more than one slashes

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client

```
package com.java4s;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/customers")
public class RestServicePathParamJava4s {
    @GET
    @Path("{name}/{country}")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response getResultByPassingValue(
                @PathParam("name") String name,
                @PathParam("country") String country) {

        String output = "Customer name - "+name+", Country - "+country+"";
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }
}
```

In web.xml I have specified URL pattern as `/rest/*` and in `RestServicePathParamJava4s.java` we specified class level `@Path` as `/customers` and method level `@Path` as  `{name}/{country}`

So the final URL should be

```
http://localhost:2013/RestPathParamAnnotationExample/rest/customers/Java4/USA
```

and the response should be displayed as

```
Customer name - Java4, Country - USA
```

If I give the 2 input given below it is showing an error. How to solve this?

```
http://localhost:2013/RestPathParamAnnotationExample/rest/customers/Java4:kum77./@.com/USA`
```

Here `Java4:kum77./@.com` this one is one string and it contains forward slash. how to accept this by using `@PathParam` or whatever I need to use `MultivaluedMap`. If somebody knows this plz help me. if anyone knows what is `MultivaluedMap`, give me a simple example?

Comment: As already answered by @peeskillet, regular expressions can be used. This is also mentioned in the [JAX-RS specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr339/index.html) itself (Section 3.4 URI Templates)

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to use a regex for for the `name` path expression

```
@Path("{name: .*}/{country}")
```

This will allow anything to be in the `name` template, and the last segment will be the `country`.

Test

```
@Path("path")
public class PathParamResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{name: .*}/{country}")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response getResultByPassingValue(@PathParam("name") String name,
                                            @PathParam("country") String country) {

        String output = "Customer name - " + name + ", Country - " + country + "";
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

> `$ curl  http://localhost:8080/api/path/Java4:kum77./@.com/USA`
>   `Customer name - Java4:kum77./@.com, Country - USA`
>
> `$ curl  http://localhost:8080/api/path/Java4/USA`
>   `Customer name - Java4, Country - USA`

Comment: @paul-samsotha how does `.*` differ than `.+` , as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985439)

Comment: @Shamil in most languages, [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8575281/2587435). It's related to regex.