# How to allow slashes in path param in jax-rs endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, path-parameter, javax.ws.rs

I have an endpoint as:

```
@Path("/products")

    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public interface Products {

        @PUT
        @Path("/{productId}")
        ....
    }
```

I have a jax-rs client implemented for this service and have it imported in the another service that I am calling this from.

So I am calling the client as below from my second service

```
public String updateProduct(String productId){
..
  return client.target(this.getBaseUrl()).path("products/").path(productId).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).put(Entity.json(""), String.class);
}
```

If I have a product with slashes say "**control/register app**" , the service does not seem to take it well. I did encode the productId before making a call to the service and then decoded it once received. But that doesnt seem to work and I get a 404 not found. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@PathVariable in SpringBoot with slashes in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470421/pathvariable-in-springboot-with-slashes-in-url)

Comment: @P.J.Meisch It's not a duplicate of the above mentioned question, once the OP is using JAX-RS instead of Spring MVC for the REST API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `@Path("{productId : .+}")` should work.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Comment: @cassiomolin Why does this answer work, is this a regex?

Comment: @CyriacGeorge, It's a regex: `.` means any symbol and `+` at least one or more.