# Redirect URLs but ignore if blank

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I currently redirect URL's using the code below within a `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ /news/page.php?ref=$1
```

This works perfectly and enables me to run a script within `page.php` to retrieve the correct article. The issue I have is that `/news/` gets redirected to `page.php`, even though no article is specified within the url. How can I modify this code to avoid this.

Currently as a quick fix I have put a condition at the beginning of the `page.php` file that checks if `ref` is set and if not then redirect to `/news/index.php`. This works because I have specified a file, `index.php`. I would like the url `/news/` to resolve without `index.php` having to be specified.

Comment: If you want the solution in .htaccess please don't tag it as php :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `^news/(.+)$` in your pattern.

What different between `*` and `+` you can read in [regex-plus-vs-star-difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575281/regex-plus-vs-star-difference)

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a try. What's the difference between`(.*)` and `(.+)`?

Comment: What different between `*` and `+` you can read in [regex-plus-vs-star-difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575281/regex-plus-vs-star-difference)

Comment: @steve as usual * is 0 or more and + is 1 or more

Comment: Thanks @VijayaSankarN

Comment: Thanks for the link. Still trying to get my head around `regex`