# Jmeter regular expression extractor not extracting what I want

Tags: jmeter

I have a link in my Request -

```
example.com/people/3176972
```

and my regular expression extractor is-

**Regular expression**: `example.com/people/(.+?)`

**Template**: `$1$`

**Match no**: `1`

but it is only extracting only 3.  I want to extract 3176972 number.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend your regular expression to look like `example.com/people/(.*)` or `example.com/people/(\d+)` as your regex stops after first match.

See [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of JMeter's User Manual for more information on JMeter Regular Expressions.

Convenient way of testing regular expressions is using "RegExp Tester" mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

[image: RegExp Tester]

Check out [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more information on different debugging techniques for JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks all for who responded.  This is one of the best threads that I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this regular expression:

```
[0-9]+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve anything after the last slash, then just remove question mark from your expression:

```
example.com/people/(.+)
```

(question mark tells it to be [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575281/regex-plus-vs-star-difference), hence it's taking 1 character).

If the last portion is always numeric, use

```
example.com/people/([0-9]+)
```