# PowerShell change something you don't know

Tags: powershell, variables

I need to change a Property file with a PowerShell script.

The line in the property file looks like this:

> max.tree.children.threshold="Here is a number which I can't know"

So my script reads the file and finds this line but I can't say that he should overwrite this number because I don't know the number?

Can I set a variable where you don't know what's in there?

```
ForEach($Datei in Get-ChildItem $test1) {
    # Get-Content liest eine Texdatei Zeile für Zeile ein
    # in der Variablen $Zeilen steht deshalb eine Liste von Zeilen (Array)
    $Zeilen =  Get-Content -Path $Datei.Fullname
    # Die Datei befindet sich nun Komplett im Speicher (in der Variablen $Zeilen)
    # deshalb können wir die Datei überschreiben

    # Zeilen Zähler, wird nur gebraucht um die erste Zeile zu erkennen
    $ZeilenZähler = 1

    # jede Zeile abarbeiten
    foreach($Zeile in $Zeilen)
    {
        # Hier findet meine Dateiveränderung statt.
        # Beispiel: Alle Buchstaben 'a' durch den Buchstaben 'o' ersetzen
        $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "max.tree.children.threshold="Dont know whats here!"","max.tree.children.threshold=300"

        #Veränderte Zeile anzeigen lassen
        Write-Host "Geänderte Zeile in Datei $($Datei.Fullname)"
        Write-Host $Zeile

        # Nur bei der ersten Zeile wird die Alte Datei ("leer") neu angelegt (überschrieben)!
        If($ZeilenZähler -eq 1 ) {
           Out-File -FilePath $Datei.Fullname -InputObject $Zeile -Force
        }
        Else {
            # jede weitere Zeile an die neue erstellte Datei anhängen (Parameter Append)
            Out-File -FilePath $Datei.Fullname -InputObject $Zeile -Force -Append
        }

        # Zeilenzähler hochsetzen
        $ZeilenZähler++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using regular expressions:

```
...
$file =  $Datei.Fullname
(Get-Content $file) -replace "max.tree.children.threshold=\d+","max.tree.children.threshold=300" | Set-Content $file
...
```

We are first reading the content of the file and replacing everything that matches `max.tree.children.threshold=\d+` (the `\d+` will match the rest of the line as long as it digits) with `max.tree.children.threshold=300`.

Comment: Where `.+` is [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) that stands for ["match one or more characters of something"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8575332/5039142)

Comment: Agree with @gms0ulman, `.+` is too generic as the OP asked for digits

Comment: Megabeets, you have edited your answer according to what we said without changing your explanation.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, fixed :)

Comment: replace `\d+` with `.+` to match every character

Answer (score 0):

To specifically check for digits, you can check a number using `\d+` which means one or more digits in regular expressions

```
$Zeile = $Zeile -replace "max.tree.children.threshold=\d+","max.tree.children.threshold=300"
```