# There is problem in regex(python) I don't know How *? works, i'll post the code below

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Example-1

```
import re
data = 'astlewoieroiweru@89in.if hd'
stufff = re.findall('@([0-9]*?)', data)
print(stufff)
```

it prints `['']` but why but there is number after the `@` symbol , I know it follows non-greedy
it is supposed to print `['8']` but it doesn't why? I need someone to explain me this code.

Example-2

```
import re
data = 'astlewoieroiweru@89in.if hd'
stufff = re.findall('@([0-9]*)', data)
print(stufff)
```

I know it follows greedy so it took the number after `@` and stops when it sees the i, so the output is `['89']`. Please explain the example-1, thank you!

Comment: Try regex101.com, it has an interactive tool that lets you enter a regex and a test string, and it explains why the pattern did (or didn't) match

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I know it follows non-greedy it is supposed to print ['8'] but it doesn't why?" it prints `['']` because it is non-greedy. Try to follow the logic carefully. Why should it match the `8`? If it is non-greedy, then it should match as few things as possible, right? *And it is allowed to match zero things, right?* (Because it says `*`, and not `+`?) So, zero things is a valid match, and that's the best it can do, so that's what it does.

Comment: @InSync if it is not a typo (i.e., failure to think clearly), then I think it is rather a question about the difference between `*?` and `+?` - which is really just a question about the difference between `*` and `+`.

Comment: Agree. In that case, the duplicate target would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8575281).

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/LKu0aC/1 clearly shows `([0-9]*?)` matching an empty string (see the contents of group 1).