# Powershell3: discern and display last n Lines from an ascii file

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing, file-get-contents, select-string

I think this should be simple.  I write the logging output of `xcopy` to a plain text file, with a daily delimiter (literally)
`"++++++++++++++++++++Tue 07/03/2018 0900 PM"` appended to the log file prior to each daily backup.
So the last lines in the file typically look like this:

[image: daily delimiter]

A new day appends a new delimiter line and so on.

I want to display the LAST delimiter and the lines which follow it to `eof`.

The schema I've tried `GET-Content, Select-String -Context 0,20` don't work,

`PS` says my search string **++++++++++++++++++++** isn't a regular expression, doesn't recognize path etc. etc.  Any help?

**Memory and time are not at issue**.  Sorry if this is too simple.

Comment: Know I'm not supposed to, but I must Thank you Guyz for the excellent directions and comments.  Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[msjqu's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51181788/45375) explains the need to escape `+` chars. as `\+` in a regex in order for these chars. to be treated as *literals*.

Thus, the regex to match a header line - 20 `+` chars. at the start of a line (`^`) - is: `^\+{20}`

That said, if it is sufficient to detect header lines by 20 `+` signs, **`Get-Content -Delimiter`** - which supports only *literals* as delimiters - offers a **simple and efficient solution** (PSv3+; assumes input file `some.log` in the current directory `./`):

```
 $headerPrefix = '+' * 20  # -> '++++++++++++++++++++'
 $headerPrefix + (Get-Content ./some.log -Delimiter $headerPrefix -Tail 1)
```

`-Delimiter` uses the specified header-line signature to break the file into "lines" (text between instances of the delimiter, which are *blocks* of lines here) and `-Tail 1` returns the last "line" (block) by searching for it from the *end* of the file. <sup>Tip of the hat to [mjsqu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3388954/mjsqu) for helping me arrive at this solution.</sup>

---

The following **alternative solutions** are **regular-expression-based**, which enables more sophisticated header-line matching.

Note: While none of the solutions below require reading the log file into memory *as a whole*, they do *read through the entire file*, not just from the *end*.

---

We can use this in a **`switch -regex -file` statement** to process all lines of the log file in order to collect the lines that start with and follow the *last*  `^\+{20}` match; the code assumes input file path `./some.log`:

```
# Process all lines in the log file and 
# collect each block's lines along the way in 
# array $lastBlockLines, which means that after 
# all lines have been processed, $lastBlockLines contains
# the *last* block's lines.
switch -regex -file ./some.log {
  '^\+{20}' { $lastBlockLines = @($_) } # start of new block, (re)initialize array
  default   { $lastBlockLines += $_ }   # add line to block
}

# Output the last block's lines.
$lastBlockLines
```

---

**Alternatively**, *if you're willing to assume a fixed maximum number of lines in a block*, a **single-pipeline solution using `Select-String`** is possible:

```
Select-String '^\+{20}' ./some.log -Context 0,100 | Select-Object -Last 1 | 
  ForEach-Object { $_.Line; $_.Context.PostContext }
```

- `Select-String '^\+{20}' ./some.log -Context 0,100` matches all header lines in file `./some.log` and, thanks to `-Context 0, 100`, includes (up to) 100 lines that follow a matching line in the match object that is emitted (the `0` means that no lines that *precede* a matching line are to be included).
- `Select-Object -Last 1` passes only the *last* match on.
- `ForEach-Object { $_.Line; $_.Context.PostContext }` then outputs the last match's matching line as well as the up to 100 lines that follow it.

---

**If you don't mind reading the file *twice***, you can combine `Select-String` with `Get-Content ... | Select-Object -Skip`:

```
Get-Content ./some.log | Select-Object -Skip (
    (Select-String '^\+{20}' ./some.log | Select-Object -Last 1).LineNumber - 1
  )
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the match objects emitted by `Select-String` have a `.LineNumber` property reflecting the number of the line on which a given match was found.
Passing the last match's line number minus 1 to `Get-Content ... | Select-Object -Skip` then outputs the matching line as well as all subsequent ones.

Comment: I was playing around with a solution which involved reading the file from the end, until "+++++" and then stopping and regurgitating. Didn't quite get there though. I think that'd be the quickest way, if the file was absolutely huge.

Comment: @mjsqu: Indeed, reading in chunks from the end of the file until a header line is detected would indeed be the fastest approach with large files, but that requires significantly more effort and direct use of the .NET framework.

Comment: Repeat this: `get-content bigfile.txt -tail $i` incrementing `$i` until header detected?

Comment: @mjsqu: Promising in that it doesn't require reading the entire file, but does involve repeated `Get-Content` invocations that each have to open the file and search from the end, with each invocation duplicating the effort of the previous one. However, you can combine `-Delimiter ('+' * 20)` with `-Tail 1`, which only requires a single, read-from-the-end invocation - please see my update.

Comment: mklement0's first suggestion worked fast and true.  All I had to do was remove the ./ in front of some.log.  Combining -Tail command with -Delimiter . . . Brilliant!

Comment: I've not been successful researching this part of your first suggestion.  $headerPrefix = '+' * 20  # -> '++++++++++++++++++++'   Could you explain the operators  # -> , that is "hashtag hyphen greaterthan"  Thanks.

Comment: @fblackstone: `#` is the to-the-end-of-the-line comment character in PowerShell, meaning that everything that follows it on the same line is a _comment_. PowerShell lets you use `*` for string replication so that `'+' * 20` creates a string composed of 20 `+` characters - the comment is simply meant to illustrate that fact by printing the resulting string; the `->` as part of the comment is simply informal shorthand to indicate a return value (output).

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Escape the `+` in your search, use "\+\+\+" etc.

### Background

Unfortunately `+` is a reserved character in the world of regular expressions.

[What is the meaning of + in a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850217/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-regex)

It tells the engine to match the previous search operator (either a character, range or code representing a group of chars like \d - digits) one or more times. You can see more information about this error in Powershell by running the following:

```
[regex]$x = "++++"
```

Returns:

```
Cannot convert value "++++" to type "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex". Error: "parsing "++++" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing."
At line:1 char:1
+ [regex]$x = "++++"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

It is saying the quantifier (`+`) is following nothing.

So we need to escape the `+` using `\`:

```
[regex]$x = "\+\+\+\+"

$x.Match('++++')
```

Returning the following, a non-erroring match:

```
Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 4
Value    : ++++
```

### Improvement

If you know how many `+` there are, you can match on `"\+{20}"`, if there are 20. Or from the previous example:

```
[regex]$x = "\+{4}"

$x.Match('++++')
```

Comment: I will study regex and .match.  Any suggestions for finding the last occurrence, and returning (from there to eof?).  much appreciated. fb

Comment: The RegEx quantifier `{}` can also be used in a form `\+{4,20}` meaning from 4 to 20 occurences, or if the second number is is left away any number. `\+{4,}`

Answer (score 1):

Another way using a RegEx to split the file into sections.

- use `Get-Content` with the `-Raw` parameter to have one string, not an array of strings
- use a nonconsuming [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to split the file into sections starting with
  20*+  `-split '(?=\+{20})'` that are not empty `-ne ''`
- use index `[-1]` to get the last section.

Sample output

```
PS> ((Get-Content '.\LogFile.txt' -raw) -split '(?=\+{20})' -ne '')[-1]
++++++++++++++++++++Mon 07/03/2018 0900 PM
0 Files(s) copied
 Xcopy SUCCEEDED K:\ to J:\MyUSBBackups Mon 07/02/2018 0900 PM
0 Files(s) copied
 Xcopy SUCCEEDED K:\ to J:\MyUSBBackups\OutlookBak Mon 07/02/2018 0900 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd change that logging format so that it is more object friendly and use as normal.

However, based on what you have posted. Here is one way to go at this, I am sure there are more elegant ways, but this is q&d (quick and dirty.)
Also, as a military vet (20+ years) and still live and work on military time, 0900 is 9:00 AM where as 2100 is 9:00 PM.  8^} ... Just saying …

```
# Get the lines in the file
($DataSet = Get-Content -Path '.\LogFile.txt')

# Results

++++++++++++++++++++Mon 07/02/2018 0900 PM
0 Files(s) copied
 Xcopy SUCCEEDED K:\ to J:\MyUSBBackups Mon 07/02/2018 0900 PM
0 Files(s) copied
 Xcopy SUCCEEDED K:\ to J:\MyUSBBackups\OutlookBak Mon 07/02/2018 0900 PM
++++++++++++++++++++Mon 07/03/2018 0900 PM
0 Files(s) copied
 Xcopy SUCCEEDED K:\ to J:\MyUSBBackups Mon 07/02/2018 0900 PM
0 Files(s) copied
 Xcopy SUCCEEDED K:\ to J:\MyUSBBackups\OutlookBak Mon 07/02/2018 0900 PM



 # Get the index of the LastDateEntry, using a string match (RegEx)
($LastDateEntry = (Get-Content -Path '.\LogFile.txt' | %{$_ | Select-String -Pattern '[+].*'}) | Select -Last 1)

# Results

++++++++++++++++++++Mon 07/03/2018 0900 PM


# Get the LastDateEntryIndex
($DateIndex = (Get-Content -Path '.\LogFile.txt').IndexOf($LastDateEntry))

# Results

5



 # Get the data using the index
ForEach($Line in $DataSet)
{
    If ($Line.ReadCount -ge $DateIndex)
    {
    Get-Content -Path '.\LogFile.txt' | Select-Object -Index ($Line.ReadCount)
    }
}

# Results

++++++++++++++++++++Mon 07/03/2018 0900 PM
0 Files(s) copied
 Xcopy SUCCEEDED K:\ to J:\MyUSBBackups Mon 07/02/2018 0900 PM
0 Files(s) copied
 Xcopy SUCCEEDED K:\ to J:\MyUSBBackups\OutlookBak Mon 07/02/2018 0900 PM
```

Comment: As written, I wouldn't call your solution quick (neither to write nor to execute), but it contains the seed of a much shorter, faster solution, which requires neither line-by-line iteration nor loading the file into memory as a whole (though it does involve reading the file _twice_):
`$lineNo = (Select-String '[+].*' '.\LogFile.txt' | Select -Last 1).LineNumber; Get-Content '.\LogFile.txt' | Select -Skip ($lineNo - 1)`