# HTML5regex - particular characters + atleast one alphabetic digit

Tags: regex, html, forms, validation

I'm using input pattern attribute to valiate a form. I have some text fields that allow aplphanumeric digits, some selected characters (',-, accented chars, spaces) and at least one alphabetic character, with a min. length of 3.

my current regex is:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z-'áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚàèìòù ]{3,100}
```

and I can't really grasp the concept of how to require at least one character; I know I should use +, but the rest of the regexp fails.

Comment: The `{3,100}` is currently repeating the previous token (the character set) 3 to 100 times, do you want to change that to `+`? What do you mean, `rest of the regexp fails`?

Comment: Side note: Instead of `{3,100}`, you could use `{3,}`, it won't matter though.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3850256/3832970). You are probably mixing quantifiers.

Comment: It seems to me that you are confused about the `+`. `+` is the same as `{1,}`. In simple cases you get away with `*` and `+` but in more complex cases you need `{n,m}` or a variation thereof.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a great resource for tinkering with regular expressions.

Comment: I solved this by adding a positive lookahead to make sure there was at least one alphanumeric character, then by checking other special characters I needed in the following square brackets. full regexp is (?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9'-áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚàèìòù ]{3,100}