# Why does my Regex create an internal server error with "++" but not any other combination of special characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to create a basic search that will return results from a Mongo database. The query should match values that are either the complete value or within the value. For example, a search of `C` should return `C, C#, C++`. Additionally, `Java` should return both `Java, Javascript`. I have a simple implementation currently set up that can accomplish this, however if I search for the query `C++`, I am returned with an internal server error. Searching `C+` will return a successful search with `C++` being listed. This only occurs with a `++` in the query, as searches with double special characters (`//, --, $$, etc.`) will return successfully.

I have attempted using the Javascript `RegExp` function to accomplish this, however I am new to regex and am sure this is where my problem is originating from. The current implementation

1. Takes the search query from the input and encodes it
2. Passes the query to the controller which applies the `RegExp` function
3. Finds the results against the database and returns the results in a JSON object

**AJAX Call for Search**

```
function getSearchResults() {
    var query = $("#searchInput").val(); //search value
    if(query === '') {
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/items/search?search=' + encodeURIComponent(query), //url with search query
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loadingOverlay').css('visibility', 'visible');
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $('#itemContentMain').bootstrapTable({data: result});
                $('#itemContentMain').bootstrapTable('load', result);
                $('#loadingOverlay').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert("The search failed to return results: " + thrownError);
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Controller**

```
itemController.search = function(req, res) {
    var regexEx = new RegExp(req.query.search, "i"); //ignore case
    Item.find({ $or: [{name: regexEx}, {category: regexEx}, {subcategory: regexEx},
        {status: regexEx}, {description: regexEx}]}).exec(function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error:", err);
        } else {
            console.log("Search returning results");
            res.send(items);
        }
   });
};
```

I have read that a `++` in Regex is a Possessive Quantifier so that if the engine fails matching, will not go back and try to undo the matches it made. However when the query is reaching the RegExp function, it is encoded as `/items/search?search=%2B%2B`. What is happening when the `++` is passed in the query, and how can I mitigate the internal server error that it is producing?

Comment: If you want to use + literally (to match a plus character), you need escape it with `\ ` in the pattern.

Comment: I cannot stress enough how dangerous it is to construct a `RegExp` directly from user input. This leaves your server open to DDoS attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` has a [special meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850217/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-regex) in [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) and cannot be used in the form `++`. You need to escape the regex.

Using this function <sup>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex)</sup>:

```
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}
```

you can replace:

```
var regexEx = new RegExp(req.query.search, "i"); //ignore case
```

with

```
var regexEx = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(req.query.search), "i"); //ignore case
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can repeat the error easily by creating a simple regex : `/c++/` within the browser's console, which will throw the following message (may vary depending on the browser):

> SyntaxError: nothing to repeat

---

**Side note**: this is quite a bad idea to allow user to search for raw input.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. As you and others have stated though, this is ultimately (very) bad practice. What would be a better method to go about using?

Comment: Well, @Ryan, escaping it will protect you against some DDoS attacks, which is a good first step.